# How mysql index is created and What cause mysql index corrupt when creating

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I was doing TPCC test on mysql, when I create index with the code followed, I encountered an error `ERROR 1034 (HY000) at line 3: Index for table 'stock' is corrupt; try to repair it`, a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r39EN.png) is attached.

```
use tpccrunner1000;

alter table stock add constraint pk_stock
  primary key (s_w_id, s_i_id);

alter table item add constraint pk_item
  primary key (i_id);
```

'stock' is a big table and has 100,000,000 rows.

I have tried to add `innodb_buffer_pool_size` but it seems not helpful.

How can I correctly run this code?

And I would be much more grateful if you could also help me understand how mysql indexes are built.

Thank you!

[`SHOW CREATE TABLE stock`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC5bd.png)

[Disk usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTLf0.png)

[The size of Table is 35GB+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHFDO.png)

Comment: mysql or mariadb? xampp?

Comment: When you add PK to the table then the whole table is rebuilt (copied). 100kk rows rewriting must be long enough... does this process was finished?

Comment: It's just mariadb on centos. And the process is not finished. I have attached a screenshot to show the error.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  How big (in GB) is the table?  How much free disk space?  And please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE stock` if that doesn't fail, too.

Comment: I see only 2 lines; please try to identity what "line 3" is.

Comment: I have about 1T RAM, and I set `innodb_buffer_pool_size=150G`

Comment: And does "line3"  means third line of mysql code？If so I have attached it to the code block.